# How to find entity from frontend in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm learning spring boot from a project https://github.com/rstyro/admin
In page/role/list.html,there is code:

```
     <button th:if="${QX.add == '1' && QX.query == '1'}" class="btn btn-success 
         btn-sm" id="addRole"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;add role</button>
```

I want to check what is this QX entity, So I go to RoleController.java

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/list",method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public Object list(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("roles", roleService.list());
        return "page/role/list";
    }
```

then RoleService.java

```
@Service
public class RoleService implements IRoleService{

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;
    
    @Autowired
    private MenuService menuService;
    
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    @Override
    public List<ParameterMap> list() {
        return roleDao.list();
    }
```

then RoleDao.java

```
public interface RoleDao {
    public List<ParameterMap> list();
    public List<ParameterMap> getRoleByuId(ParameterMap pm);
    public ParameterMap getRoleById(ParameterMap pm);
    public void updateRoleQX(ParameterMap pm);
    public void addRole(ParameterMap pm);
    public void delRole(String roleId);
    public void delUserRole(String roleId);
}
```

and RoleMapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.lrs.admin.dao.RoleDao" >
    <select id="list"  resultType="pm">
        SELECT 
            role_id,
            role_name,
            role_desc,
            rights,
            add_qx,
            del_qx,
            edit_qx,
            query_qx
        from 
            sys_role
    </select>
```

and Role.java

```
public class Role {
    private long roleId;
    private String roleName;
    private String roleDesc;
    private String rights;
    private String addQX;
    private String delQX;
    private String editQX;
    private String queryQX;
    public long getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }
```

But nothing is there. Am I missing something? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

He is calling

```
   return roleDao.list();
```

But there is no implementation of that statement, RoleDao interface is not implemented anywhere. Which means **there is no** bean called `roleDao`, which means, you cannot run this code. It will give you error.

The author probably did not share RoleDao implementation.

Comment: Sorry I forget to add there is  a mapper for the Dao.